# Can Xbox One S and DualShock 4 controllers work over bluetooth at the same time?

Tags: pc, ps4, controllers, xbox-one

I just bought a Xbox One S controller and a Bluetooth 4.0 CSR dongle for my PC.
It works great.

Now I want to play games (mostly FIFA) with my brother and I need to buy another controller. I listed my preferred ways but I don't know if they work.

If anyone has tried these scenarios or is %100 sure that one way works please let me know.

1. Xbox One S controller and DS4 over BT
2. Two Xbox One S controllers over BT (as far as I searched this one is not possible)
3. Xbox One S controller over BT and another controller (whatever it may be) over USB cable

I know that Microsoft and Sony each have their official dongle for connecting their controllers to PC (and this will be my last option if above ways wont work) but since I have Bluetooth I was wondering If the two can work together.

Comment: I don't see any problem scenario 3 would make only because they are essentially on separate "channels."

Comment: Yes they can work together. Bluetooth is a protocol that supports multiple devices. The real question probably should be whether latency is impacted in a way that would make playing unreasonable. Unfortunately, I haven't tested it. But from a technological point of view (regarding Bluetooth), nothing seems to prohibit any or your scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pair all of them to the same PC with one Bluetooth dongle. I just tested with two Xbox One S controllers and two Dualshock 4 controllers and it worked fine. You may need third party drivers for the Dualshock 4 depending on the software you're trying to use it with.

Don't buy the official dongles. The Xbox One dongle is only for the OLD pre-S gamepads that do not support Bluetooth. The dongle does nothing for Xbox One S controllers. The Dualshock 4 dongle will work but it can only handle one controller at a time and isn't necessary if you already have a working Bluetooth dongle.

Both controllers work well with a micro USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Xbox website states - "We recommend connecting only one controller at a time using Bluetooth." You can freely connect PS4 DualShock 4 controller via USB as long as cable length is enough.